# Cant call service method in Angular factory (using Ionic)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Using Ionic v1 and trying to call a function from within a factory using `this` or `self` but getting error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'connectArd'
```

Code:

```
angular.module('hardware.services', [])

    .factory('hardwareserv', function($http,$rootScope,$state,$cordovaBluetoothSerial) {

 var hardwareService = {};

        hardwareService.connectArd = function(MACaddress) {
            window.bluetoothSerial.connect(MACaddress, this.successConnect2, this.failConnect);              
        };  

       this.connectArd(MACdevicex); // calling above method

        return hardwareService;

    });
```

Comment: I don't see `hardwareService` anywhere defined. This piece of code doesn't show that `this` is equal to `hardwareService`

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, but have defined it using var hardwareService = {};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must call `hardwareService.connectArd(MACdevicex)`.

Since you are assigning function to hardwareService object , you must call it from there.not from factory scope

Comment: Since you are assigning function to `hardwareService` object , you must call it from there.not from factory scope.